# How to get Persian month name with library?

Tags: android, android-calendar, farsi, persian-calendar

I use this library

```
com.github.samanzamani.persiandate:PersianDate:0.8
```

I want to make a list of the Persian month name and check for existing transaction in the month. Like the code below, I want to do this using the library above

```
private long getMonthTimestamp(long timestamp) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date(timestamp));

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

I am a beginner.

Comment: Please go through the readme.md of the library. There is an [**example**](https://github.com/samanzamani/PersianDate#example) which will help you

Comment: Thanks. I studied. I tried several times. But I couldn't do it. You can do an example with this library similar to the code above

Comment: `PersianDate pd = new PersianDate(timestamp);` Next you can use the set methods which you want to set and finally use `PersianDateFormat pdformater2 = new PersianDateFormat('y F j');
pdformater2.format(pdate);`